# Pandas how to combine two table without key

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

What i want is very simple , but pandas is very confusing for me , i just want combine twoo table

Table 1:

```
Column 1,Column 2

Value1, Value1

Value2, Value2
```

Table 2:

```
Column 3,Column 4

Value1, Value1

Value2, Value2
```

what i want

```
Column 1,Column 2,Column 3,Column 4
Value1, Value1, Value1, Value1
Value2, Value2, Value2, Value2
```

Note : there is no same column , no key , just combine row by row , so i think "merge" will not work

Comment: Use `pd.concat([table1, table2], axis=1)`

Comment: with a disclaimer i don't use Pandas, i would say that it seems to work like sql except with really strange syntax.  What you want to do is pretty much impossible in a relational database without primary keys as there is no way to know what order the data is in from one query to the next.  If i am wrong i apologize.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have the following dataframes/tables:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': [4,5,6]})

   a  b
0  1  4
1  2  5
2  3  6

df2 = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'c': [7,8,9], 'd': [10,11,11]})

   c   d
0  7  10
1  8  11
2  9  11
```

With the following line of code you can concatenate them:

```
new = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   a  b  c   d
0  1  4  7  10
1  2  5  8  11
2  3  6  9  11
```